# If X is a characteristic vector of matrix A , then kX is also a character vector of A corresponding to the same characteristic value

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, matrix-equations

If X is a characteristic vector of matrix A corresponding to characteristic value lambda, then kX is also a character vector of A corresponding to the same characteristic value lambda where k is a non-zero vector.

HOW ?

Comment: One line proof. Take the definition of an eigenvector, and substitute $kX$

Comment: Can you show how? @BrevanEllefsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $AX=\lambda X$.

Then $A(kX)=k(AX)$ by associativity (and commutativity of multiplication by a scalar).

So $A(kX)=k\lambda X=\lambda(kX)$ as required.